# Two connections/cursors in mysqldb - commands out of sync error

Tags: python, sql, cursor, database-connection, mysql-python

I'm using mysqldb in part of a script to copy information from one database to another.  A snippet of the code I have is as follows:

```
connection1 = mysqldb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'old_database')
connection2 = mysqldb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'new_database')
connection2.autocommit(True)

cursor2 = connection2.cursor()
cursor2.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...")
//if I put a cursor2.close() or a connection2.commit() here, that throws the error as well

cursor1 = connection1.cursor()
cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM old_database.data")
sql = "INSERT INTO new_database.data(a, b) VALUES (%s, %s)"
for row in cursor1.fetchall():
    a, b = row
    data = [a, b]
    cursor2.execute(sql, data)
print "done"
connection1.close()
connection2.close()
```

I keep getting the following exception:
Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") 
whenever it gets to the `cursor2.execute(sql, data)` line.  I know there are concurrency issues with using two cursors on the same connection, but how can I do this with two cursors on two distinct connections?

Update: there's no multi-threading going on anywhere, either.
Adding explicit `commit()` calls on connections or attempting to call close() on cursors causes the same error to be thrown, but on the line with the new call...

Update:  I'm using both connections on the same port, does that affect anything?

Comment: Try using `cursor2.executemany` on the whole lot of data.

Comment: Can you give some guidance on how to do that in this context?  I'd need to extract all the data from cursor1 into a list of some sort to pass along to cursor2, right?

Comment: Oh, in my actual code I have constructs like this where I modify values within the loop though, so I don't think I can use execute_many here.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `connection2.commit()` after your first execute call. EDIT: and each subsequent one.

You can also call `connection2.autocommit(True)` to have it commit after each execute automatically.

You may need to call `cursor2.close()` and then `cursor2 = connection2.cursor()` after each commit.

Comment: Thanks for the response willy; I tried that but got the same error, but this time at the call to connection2.commit() instead.  Any other ideas?

Comment: See my edit. You need to call it each time, or use `autocommit(True)` before any `execute` calls.

Comment: I've set autocommit to True for connection2, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything... :/

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with MySQLdb directly. Did you set autocommit before you created the cursor? I can't remember if that makes a difference. Also, I generally always liked the ability to roll stuff back, so I manually committed most of the time. Try calling `cursor2.commit()` after every single call to `execute`, including the one in the loop.

Comment: Yes, I set it before opening the cursors.  So far anywhere that I've added an explicit commit() call, it's thrown the error immediately at that line.

Comment: Try closing and re-opening the cursor. Looking at some of my old code, it appears I always do that, so that might've been the answer when I had this problem.

Comment: Hmm, tried this and now the cursor.close() call is throwing the error!  No idea what's going on here.

Comment: You tried it after every repetition of `execute` and `commit`? The pattern I'm seeing repeated in my old code is `execute`, then `commit`, then `close`, for every single call. This means after the create table, then you'll open a new cursor at the beginning of your loop. Then execute and close it inside of your loop.

Comment: I did... I just figured out what the error was though.  My sql CREATE statement, which I didn't include fully here (and probably should have), had multiple statements with ;s in it.  I had to separate those out into separate cursor(), execute(), close() iterations.  Thanks for the suggestions - they pointed me in the right direction for debugging!

Comment: @user2048643 You shouldn't have to close the connection each time. You should actually only have to use 2 cursors the whole time. `cursor.execute` will only execute one SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to commit cursor2 after creating the table then open cursor1 after commiting cursor2

Comment: Committing the cursor did the same thing as committing the connection - same error but now at the commit line.

Comment: I still get the same error committing cursor2, even if I don't open cursor1 until afterwards.